# What can be the maximum numbers of students?

Tags: combinatorics

8 questions are prepared for an exam. These questions are distributed among student such that at most one question in common in any two students and each student receives theee questions. Find maximum numbers of students.

I have solved this problem but want to know a solution by PIgeon Hole Principle. Thanks.

Comment: PHP refers to the *PigeonHole Principle* (rather than the programming language), right?

Comment: Each student receives **one** question?

Comment: Each student receives three questions.

Comment: "I have solved this problem" Show your solution.